# How to compose new Camera Rotation with previous transformations?

Tags: three.js, webgl, transformation

I'm trying to implement something similar to FlyControls in THREE.js, but I can not for the life of me figure out how to correctly rotate the camera's pitch:

http://radiantjs.herokuapp.com/

Press the A or Z keys to "look up / look down." Because the initial position in that demo is already rotated on the yaw axis, the pitch essentially looks like roll.

My code for updating the camera's position and rotation are as follows:

```
/**
 * Updates this View. This is called once per frame.
 * 
 * @param {Number} delta The length of the frame (16 / milliseconds).
 */
update: function(delta) {

        if (this.velocity.length() < 0.15) {
            this.velocity.clear()
        } else {
            this.velocity.multiplyScalar(0.85 * delta)
        }

        if (this.velocity.x || this.velocity.y || this.velocity.z) {
            this.camera.position = this.camera.localToWorld(this.velocity.clone())
            this.camera.position.clamp(-16384, 16384)
        }

        if (this.rotation.length() < 0.15) {
            this.rotation.clear()
        } else {
            this.rotation.multiplyScalar(0.85 * delta)
        }

        if (this.rotation.x || this.rotation.y) {
            var rotation = this.rotation.clone().multiplyScalar(Math.PI / 180)
            this.camera.rotation.add(rotation)
        }
    }
```

The full code is also available here:
https://github.com/jdolan/radiantjs/blob/master/public/scripts/main/view.js#L291

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Just an update, this demo is much more testable now. Still need help with rotation tho!

Answer (score 3):

A kind user in the THREE.js IRC channel explained that the easiest way to accomplish what I wanted to do was to wrap the camera in a separate object (a parent / container). Translation and yaw are applied to the container, while pitch is applied to the camera itself:

```
this.boom = new THREE.Object3D()
this.boom.position.copy(params.position)
this.boom.up.set(0, 0, 1)
this.boom.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0).add(params.position))

this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(this.fov, this.aspect, 0.1, 4096)

this.boom.add(this.camera)
this.scene.add(this.boom)
```

Then to apply my transform at each frame:

```
if (this.velocity.length() < 0.15) {
    this.velocity.clear()
} else {
    this.velocity.multiplyScalar(0.85)
}

if (this.velocity.x || this.velocity.y || this.velocity.z) {
    this.boom.translate(3, this.velocity.clone())
    this.boom.position.clamp(-16384, 16384)
}

if (this.avelocity.length() < 0.15) {
    this.avelocity.clear()
} else {
    this.avelocity.multiplyScalar(0.85)
}

if (this.avelocity.x || this.avelocity.y) {
    var rotation = this.avelocity.clone().multiplyScalar(Math.PI / 180)
    this.boom.rotation.y += rotation.y
    this.camera.rotation.x += rotation.x
}
```

Works like a charm! Note that, again, yaw is applied to `this.boom` while pitch is applied to `this.camera`. This has the effect of rotating the camera relative to the boom, rather than relative to the scene.

Answer (score 2):

The way I do is to first set `camera.eulerOrder = "YXZ";`, then I can use `camera.rotation.y` as yaw and `camera.rotation.x` as pitch.

For movement I use `camera.translateZ` for forward/backward and `camera.translateX` for strafe. Since I want the player to always jump up (or fall) even when they are looking directly up/down I use `camera.position.y += velocity.y;` instead of `translateY` (which is based on rotation).

I'm not sure if this is better or worse than using a container instead.